# Back Buttons from navigation bar are overlapping , swift 4

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I was trying to customize my back button according to [this](https://medium.com/@tjcarney89/implementing-a-custom-back-button-in-swift-39e4ab55c71) tutorial. 
In AppDelegate,

```
let barButtonAppearence = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    let backButton = UIImage(named: "back_arrow")
    let backButtonImage = backButton?.stretchableImage(withLeftCapWidth: 0, topCapHeight: 10)
    barButtonAppearence.setBackButtonBackgroundImage(backButtonImage, for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
    return true
}
```

And then it is conflicting with the existing one (which appeared automatically because of segue(Show).

[image]

So I need to remove the blue one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things need to accomplish what you are trying to achieve:

- Changing the back button's default image to your supplied image
- Removing the title from the back button item

### To change back button's image:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Remember, this will change every navigation bar's back button image in your app
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "backButton")
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "backButton")
    return true
}
```

Note: If you don't want that all your navigation bar back button to have the supplied image, you may need to subclass `UINavigationController` and update its navigation bar.

### Removing the title from the back button item:

We will do this by adding a method to any `UIViewController` through extension. Extension method will be used here so that any `UIViewController` can be able to have this behavior when it wants.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func removeNavigationBarBackButtonItemTitle() {
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    }
}
```

Now, in any push transition for **VC A** -> **VC B** you need to hide the back button's title. But you have to invoke the method `removeNavigationBarBackButtonItemTitle()` from **VC A**. Just remember this and you are good to go.

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        removeNavigationBarBackButtonItemTitle()
    }
}
```

You will find a demo [here](https://github.com/M-I-N/GradientNavigationBar). The demo also has some other implementations too. But you will get what you need and what I've said above.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried replacing it this way:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "back_arrow")
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "back_arrow")
```

I have tried this on `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method in `AppDelegate`

Comment: only default appeared (blue one)

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative solution to set tint color clear. See the below-modified code of your.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    let backButton = UIImage(named: "back_arrow")
    let backButtonImage = backButton?.stretchableImage(withLeftCapWidth: 0, topCapHeight: 10)
    barButtonAppearence.setBackButtonBackgroundImage(backButtonImage, for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
 barButtonAppearence.tintColor = UIColor.clear
    return true
```

}